# Validate a form on the fly or skip a rule in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I have a **entity** and **validations.yml**... for register a new record in the entity(table) I have a rule for a unique email and works fine but when I try to make a simple login passing the email and password, and when pass for **$form->isValid()** I don't want to display the message about **Email already taken** instead I want to skip this rule or a way to just compare the email and password and only compare if the email is empty or password aswell.

Or whether exists a way to add a validation on the fly.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What you want is validation groups. http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#validation-groups though personally I just create different form types and apply validators directly to the form elements.

Comment: @Cerad, write it as an answer and I'll upvote it.

Comment: Appreciate the thought.  I'll wait till SoldierCorp comes back.

Comment: @Cerad Hello, sorry for late... I'm testing the validation groups and hope will work, i will message you once done of whether have a problem.

Comment: @Cerad Can you post some example about the way you use to validate using groups, please?  I have some troubles. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry but all I can suggest is following the examples in the documentation.  I found groups to be a bit confusing to manage.  I just create different form types for different use cases and validate in the form.  I don't use the validate.yml file at all.  Maybe someone else can step in.

Comment: @Cerad Don't worry, but I solved my problem using validation groups. Thank you, can you write the answer to set as accepted please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is validation groups. symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#validation-groups

Though personally I just create different form types and apply validators directly to the form elements.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can "validate on the fly" using the Symfony validator service. It's explained quite clearly in the Symfony [validation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html) documentation. Example:

```
$author = new Author();
// ... do something to the $author object

$validator = $this->get('validator');
$errors = $validator->validate($author);

return (count($errors) > 0) ? new Response('Some Error Message') : new Response('Some Success Message');
```

You can even tell it which fields you want to validate. If you can post your actual code and what the specific problem is that you are experiencing with it, I can try to provide a more specific answer.

To validate only specific fields in your form inside your controller action:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Email;

...

$emailConstraint = new Email();

// all constraint "options" can be set this way
$emailConstraint->message = 'Invalid email address';

// use the validator to validate the value
$errorList = $this->get('validator')->validateValue(
    $email,
    $emailConstraint
);

if (count($errorList) == 0) {
    // this IS a valid email address, do something
} else {
    // this is *not* a valid email address
    $errorMessage = $errorList[0]->getMessage();

    // ... do something with the error
}
```

More on [validating raw values](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#book-validation-raw-values).

Comment: Yes but, this validator will take the rules of validation.yml or if not, where I can put the custom message for the validation because I want to validate the email using validations.yml but I want to avoid to validate the unique entity

Comment: Yes, it will use the rules in your yml file or annotations if you use that method. You can also validate ONLY specific fields. See above.

Comment: Thank you, I'm testing and I added Blank Constraint and Length to use for Email value and for Password so, how can I validate both email and password to get the errors of both? For example if the user type a wrong email and the password is empty.

Comment: To validate multiple properties, create a validation group (http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#book-validation-validation-groups) containing just the properties on your entity you want validated, and then tell the validator to validate the properties in that group. Eg: `$errors = $validator->validate($someEntity, array('SomeValidationGroup'));`

Comment: Thanks for your answers Haig, and I solved my problem using the validation groups but Cerad told me that thing first (in the comments of the post above), but anyway I will leave you +1 because now I know how to validate just 1 field.